# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in custom domain

Tags: reactjs

when i deploy my new react project to Github pages it works well but when i add a custom domain it shows error like [image]

any solutions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your server does not have the resources need to load this site. JavaScript files are chunked into small pieces to fast load the application, as you can see your site is not getting those.